# How to inc array item in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like:

```
{counts:[1,3,2]}
```

how to `$inc` any item of the array?

If it is an object, things will be much easier by using `$inc:{'counts.field': 1}`, but I don't know how to deal with an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the index of the array to achieve it.

```
                  db.collection.update({_id : id}, { $inc: { "count.0" : 1}});
```

This will increment the 0th index position of the array.

Similarly you can do "count.1" for second index etc.

Comment: thanks, this works. I think my problem comes from collection2 - a package of meteor, in which I can't use such syntax like 'count.0'